# How can I have multiple targets/executables in a single Node.js repo?

Tags: node.js, typescript, expo

I have a React Native app built using TypeScript, and I would like to also develop a number of CLI tools to help developers and 'back office' folks, also using TypeScript. I would like these to live in the same monorepo.

Based on advice from colleagues and my own research, I have tried doing this by creating a subfolder in the repo, and creating a second `package.json` (and all the other config files), and `npm install`-ing as if it were a completely separate project. It didn't take long for this to become a total mess, primarily with duplicate imports where one thing mysteriously seems to import modules from the other targets' `node_modules`, but also just remembering to re-`npm install` all the different subprojects before each commit, etc. It gets even more confusing with the TS `build` folders lying around; they're another place for people to import the wrong thing from. The confusion caused by this approach has been a significant drain on productivity, and it feels like there **has** to be a better way. So that's the question:

What is the best practice for building multiple TS/Node targets (and by "targets", I don't mean ES6 vs ESNext, I mean in the C/C++ sense: multiple output "programs", so in this case I want it to both create the bundle necessary for my RN app, but then also generate a CLI executable.) that all share code with one another, from a single monorepo?

If it matters, I am also using Expo.

Comment: I think a package.json in that subfolder is a bad idea. But I believe you can have a tsconfig.json in that sub directory which will override the one at the root. That can have different target.

Comment: My experience tells me that a `package.json` in a subfolder is a bad idea. :) I'll have to look into what I can get from a separate `tsconfig.json`. The main concern is that React Native projects pull in SOOO many packages, and my CLI tools don't need all (or really, any) of it, and I'm even a little concerned that some of the stuff with native extensions might even break the CLI tool. I suppose I could always push everything down a level and put the two projects side by side, but then code-sharing between them becomes much more cumbersome.

Comment: So what? Any executing code will only import whatever it needs and no more. And you need all those packages to tun both the CLI and the react app. I imagine any user here will want to do both of those. Also depending on how deep you want to go, a true monorepo solution like [NX](https://nx.dev/) may help. Then you have `apps/cli`, `apps/frontend`, `libs/shared-thing`, etc. But if those are your only two apps, this may be overkill

Comment: It might be time for NX. I've been flailing around with various ideas for hours now and I'd say I'm definitively *worse* off than I was when I had my subproject `package.json`. I hope someone comes through on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're essentially describing a monorepo. `pnpm` has fantastic tooling out of the box for this.

Download the `pnpm` CLI and install it:

```
$ npm i -g pnpm              # Download pnpm
$ mkdir monorepo             # Create a new monorepo folder
$ cd monorepo
$ mkdir packages             # This will be the folder where you add your
                             # apps, libraries, etc.
$ touch package.json         # Create a package.json
$ echo "{}" > package.json
```

Create a `pnpm-workspace.yaml` file and add the following:

```
packages:
  - 'packages/**'
```

Congratulations. You now have a monorepo where you can add multiple apps. Here's how it works:

- Every folder under `packages` that has a `package.json` file is now a Node app that you can control using `pnpm` from the root of your workspace.
- When you run `pnpm i` from the root, it will install all of the dependencies for **all** of your apps and libraries.
- You can even install libraries that you create locally without needing to run `npm link`, or deal with adding `file:../` to your `package.json` or any of that mess.
- `pnpm` also supports running scripts across all of your repos at the same time.

[I made an example project for you to look at.](https://github.com/divmgl/pnpm-example) In this example, you'll notice I created a library named `my-library` and a dependent app named `awesome-app`. When I ran

```
$ pwd
~/stackoverflow/packages/awesome-app
$ pnpm i my-library
```

`pnpm` knew to pick up my workspace library automatically:

```
{
  "name": "awesome-app",
  "dependencies": {
    "my-library": "workspace:0.1.0"
  }
}
```

Note the `workspace:0.1.0` that matches the version of the package I have in my repo.

I love `pnpm`. It isn't without its faults, but I've been very productive with it. There are also other alternatives, such as Lerna, and `npm` and `yarn` support their own workspace protocol. I just find `pnpm` to work the best and has the least amount of ceremony.

Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about `pnpm`, however `pnpm` and `Expo` don't get along, so I'm hesitant to accept your answer.

Comment: Oh that's unfortunate, I'm sorry to that. Yeah `pnpm` may not play well with all frameworks. Do you have a specific error you're getting in `Expo`? We can drop to a StackOverflow chat if you want to go over it

Comment: By the way, looks like Expo is now supported with `pnpm`: https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/3010

Comment: https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/3731#issuecomment-995234108

Comment: Awarding the bounty. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: @ipmcc happy to help. Let me know if you wanna debug further.

Comment: it might also be worth noting that [Lerna-Lite](https://github.com/ghiscoding/lerna-lite) now also support the `workspace:*` protocol from pnpm/yarn and Lerna doesn't yet support it (maybe in the future, who knows). I also migrated Lerna-Lite itself to pnpm because pnpm is just awesome :)